# Loading of Admob Native ads failed to load with error code 0

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I've faced with some kind of an issue.

I tried to integrate the `Admob` Native ads (recently added to Google Play Services as I realized) using

**manual**

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native

**quick start**

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start.

It was OK for a simple banner loaded by `AdView` but I really stuck when I changed to loading native ads by `AdLoader`.

I'm using Idea + Gradle and Android Annotations.

**Here is the Logcat (updated, kindly see to the end of the question):**

```
07-13 17:12:32.260    2548-2580/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-1439082442.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
07-13 17:12:32.350    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
07-13 17:12:32.350    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
07-13 17:12:32.840    2548-2580/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads-1439082442.jar' (success) ---
07-13 17:12:32.840    2548-2580/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher/cache/ads-1439082442.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 580ms
07-13 17:12:35.100    1798-1826/com.google.android.gms I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
07-13 17:12:36.360    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.<init>
07-13 17:13:36.351    2548-2612/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/Ads﹕ Timed out waiting for native ad.
07-13 17:13:36.351    2548-2613/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/Ads﹕ Timeout when loading native ad.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: CallbackFuture timed out.
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.a.a.get(SourceFile:108)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.a.b(SourceFile:156)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.a.call(SourceFile:70)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(SourceFile:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-13 17:13:36.351    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 2
07-13 17:13:36.351    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher.ads.AdmobFetcher﹕ Fetching Ad now
07-13 17:13:36.391    1798-1825/com.google.android.gms I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
07-13 17:13:36.741    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/native_ads.html (0)
07-13 17:13:36.751    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/native_ads.html (0)
07-13 17:13:36.861    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/native_ads.html (0)
07-13 17:13:36.881    2548-2548/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
```

**Here is the code for fetching the ad (I call the method `prefetchAds` from my extended `BaseAdapter` to publish the loaded ad to the `ListView`).**

```
package com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher.ads;

import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher.CbLog;
import com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher.Crypt;
import com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher.GroupWatcherApplication;
import com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdLoader;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAdOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAppInstallAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeContentAd;

public class AdmobFetcher {

 private AdLoader adLoader;
 private WeakReference<Context> mContext = new WeakReference<>(null);

...
//I call this method once, just to setup AdLoader and fetch the ad.
 public synchronized void prefetchAds(Context context) {
        mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
        setupAds();
        fetchAd();
    }

  private synchronized void setupAds() {
        String admobUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"; // the test ad unit id that is pointed in the manual
        adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(mContext.get(), admobUnitId)
                .forAppInstallAd(new NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAppInstallAdLoaded(NativeAppInstallAd appInstallAd) {
                        onAdFetched(appInstallAd); // Can't get here
                    }
                })
                .forContentAd(new NativeContentAd.OnContentAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onContentAdLoaded(NativeContentAd contentAd) {
                        onAdFetched(contentAd); // Can't get here
                    }
                })
                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        // Here I got errorCode = 0 each time (kindly check Logcat)
                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                        //.setReturnUrlsForImageAssets(true)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

 /**
     * Fetches a new native ad.
     */
    private synchronized void fetchAd() {
        Context context = mContext.get();
        if (context != null) {
            adLoader.loadAd(getAdRequest()); //Fetching the ads item
        } else {
            mFetchFailCount++;
        }
    }

     /**
     * Setup and get an AdRequest instance
     */
    private synchronized AdRequest getAdRequest() {
        String deviceId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        return new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators are added by default as test devices
                .addTestDevice(deviceId)
                .build();
    }

...
}
```

**The app's manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <application
        android:name="GroupWatcherApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity_"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:noHistory="false" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainContainerActivity_"
            android:launchMode="standard" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PreferencesActivity_"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.WatcherEditActivity_"
            android:launchMode="standard" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddGroupsActivity_"
            android:launchMode="standard" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MessageDetailsActivity_"
            android:launchMode="standard" >
        </activity>
        <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.WatcherService_"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher.environment.EnvironmentStateReceiver_"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**And finally my `build.gradle` of the module**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    } }

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal() }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'android-apt' def AAVersion = '3.3.1'

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher'
    } }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.0.Final'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.0'
    compile project(':google-licensing') }
```

**Have I missed something?**

**Or the Native ads still not supported by `Admob`?**

Also I tried such things as changing my app unit id from test to real one, testing on the emulator/device and clearing the cache data of Google Play Services on the device - the same result.

Any help/ideas will be highly appreciated...

**Updated:**
I've removed multidex mode from gradle's config and changed the `buildToolsVersion` to the latest one (22.0.1), the logcat is updated to the top of the question. Now the first call of the method `fetchAd` fails with code 2 (timeout) and the next calls fail with code 0 as earlier. Kindly take a look at the updated **Logcat**

**Updated2:**
A log for a real device  (android api level 15):

```
07-14 00:23:26.985    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
07-14 00:23:27.015    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
07-14 00:23:27.225    7698-7823/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads833267715.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
07-14 00:23:27.365    7698-7823/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads833267715.jar' (success) ---
07-14 00:23:27.365    7698-7823/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher/cache/ads833267715.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 139ms
07-14 00:23:36.424    7433-7443/? I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
07-14 00:23:36.454    7433-7863/? I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
07-14 00:23:36.504    7433-7863/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.net.ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.a.r.a
07-14 00:23:36.584    7433-7433/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.<init>
07-14 00:23:36.584    7433-7433/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.evaluateJavascript
07-14 00:23:36.594    7433-7433/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.isAttachedToWindow, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.onDraw
07-14 00:23:36.594    7433-7433/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6452: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/internal/t/h;.isAttachedToWindow ()Z
07-14 00:23:36.624    7433-7857/? D/skia﹕ WebFrame::loadStarted (1) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html
07-14 00:23:37.295    7433-7857/? D/skia﹕ WebFrame::loadStarted (0) gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=d72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D157010986198
07-14 00:23:37.295    7433-7433/? W/Ads﹕ JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=d72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D15701098619806543204%26seq_num%3D1%26rm%3D1%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1%26eid%3D46621077%252C46621098%252C318474371%26hl%3Dru%26submodel%3DHTC%2520Sensation%2520XE%2520with%2520Beats%2520Audio%2520Z715e%26gnt%3D0%26native_templates%3D1%252C2%26ma%3D0%26platform%3DHTC%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D1%26native_version%3D3%26muv%3D15%26riv%3D0%26ms%3DbBaKMM241P7ZUZbIw630exH1iY80ufKc8Z12nKVbEOI4eDpWg2KlW24F0xUKsi7r1FLSD9ISfYeAdN8C_jtjpY6xx5wG5BARDyrZUgeW_qnHTavdTzBzrpSaI1-3y19EgkD3mrsTe5XMetskcd4lTidQnf63xhT8BeE9u1LAJb1pTp_N8TssVCQNtBBRk59fPAK8olxqwKJm-nDWnLngOBSH0F_dXlmb_-ZhxT0VwHw8Hv406I5dXx2jh6YAvc0kd_cJwwBfLhCXEnxqcNCgAhLJWbdnzqf2kYziboXI8BGqqPbVNRNeKqzWB149Ri-q0no25qbKdZIbT0yuMNMkgA%26mv%3D80321300.com.android.vending%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DRU%26request_id%3Dd72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c%26am%3D0%26native_image_orientation%3Dany%26u_w%3D360%26u_h%3D640%26msid%3Dcom.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26app_name%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26an%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26net%3Dwi%26u_audio%3D3%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D0%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D0%26currts%3D4989768%26pclick%3D0%26basets%3D4989768%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D180%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26gsb%3Dwi%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.55%26cans%3D-1%26canm%3Dfalse%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26tcar%3D46%26jsv%3D176%26urll%3D1435&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1436822617303.
    (null:1)
07-14 00:23:37.295    7433-7433/? W/Web Console﹕ The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=d72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D15701098619806543204%26seq_num%3D1%26rm%3D1%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1%26eid%3D46621077%252C46621098%252C318474371%26hl%3Dru%26submodel%3DHTC%2520Sensation%2520XE%2520with%2520Beats%2520Audio%2520Z715e%26gnt%3D0%26native_templates%3D1%252C2%26ma%3D0%26platform%3DHTC%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D1%26native_version%3D3%26muv%3D15%26riv%3D0%26ms%3DbBaKMM241P7ZUZbIw630exH1iY80ufKc8Z12nKVbEOI4eDpWg2KlW24F0xUKsi7r1FLSD9ISfYeAdN8C_jtjpY6xx5wG5BARDyrZUgeW_qnHTavdTzBzrpSaI1-3y19EgkD3mrsTe5XMetskcd4lTidQnf63xhT8BeE9u1LAJb1pTp_N8TssVCQNtBBRk59fPAK8olxqwKJm-nDWnLngOBSH0F_dXlmb_-ZhxT0VwHw8Hv406I5dXx2jh6YAvc0kd_cJwwBfLhCXEnxqcNCgAhLJWbdnzqf2kYziboXI8BGqqPbVNRNeKqzWB149Ri-q0no25qbKdZIbT0yuMNMkgA%26mv%3D80321300.com.android.vending%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DRU%26request_id%3Dd72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c%26am%3D0%26native_image_orientation%3Dany%26u_w%3D360%26u_h%3D640%26msid%3Dcom.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26app_name%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26an%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26net%3Dwi%26u_audio%3D3%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D0%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D0%26currts%3D4989768%26pclick%3D0%26basets%3D4989768%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D180%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26gsb%3Dwi%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.55%26cans%3D-1%26canm%3Dfalse%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26tcar%3D46%26jsv%3D176%26urll%3D1435&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1436822617303.
            at null:1
07-14 00:23:37.335    7433-7857/? D/skia﹕ WebFrame::loadStarted (0) gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=d72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D157010986198
07-14 00:23:37.345    7433-7433/? W/Ads﹕ JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=d72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D15701098619806543204%26seq_num%3D1%26rm%3D1%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1%26eid%3D46621077%252C46621098%252C318474371%26hl%3Dru%26submodel%3DHTC%2520Sensation%2520XE%2520with%2520Beats%2520Audio%2520Z715e%26gnt%3D0%26native_templates%3D1%252C2%26ma%3D0%26platform%3DHTC%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D1%26native_version%3D3%26muv%3D15%26riv%3D0%26ms%3DbBaKMM241P7ZUZbIw630exH1iY80ufKc8Z12nKVbEOI4eDpWg2KlW24F0xUKsi7r1FLSD9ISfYeAdN8C_jtjpY6xx5wG5BARDyrZUgeW_qnHTavdTzBzrpSaI1-3y19EgkD3mrsTe5XMetskcd4lTidQnf63xhT8BeE9u1LAJb1pTp_N8TssVCQNtBBRk59fPAK8olxqwKJm-nDWnLngOBSH0F_dXlmb_-ZhxT0VwHw8Hv406I5dXx2jh6YAvc0kd_cJwwBfLhCXEnxqcNCgAhLJWbdnzqf2kYziboXI8BGqqPbVNRNeKqzWB149Ri-q0no25qbKdZIbT0yuMNMkgA%26mv%3D80321300.com.android.vending%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DRU%26request_id%3Dd72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c%26am%3D0%26native_image_orientation%3Dany%26u_w%3D360%26u_h%3D640%26msid%3Dcom.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26app_name%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26an%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26net%3Dwi%26u_audio%3D3%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D0%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D0%26currts%3D4989768%26pclick%3D0%26basets%3D4989768%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D180%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26gsb%3Dwi%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.55%26cans%3D-1%26canm%3Dfalse%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26tcar%3D46%26jsv%3D176%26urll%3D1435&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1436822617303.
    (null:1)
07-14 00:23:37.345    7433-7433/? W/Web Console﹕ The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=d72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D15701098619806543204%26seq_num%3D1%26rm%3D1%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1%26eid%3D46621077%252C46621098%252C318474371%26hl%3Dru%26submodel%3DHTC%2520Sensation%2520XE%2520with%2520Beats%2520Audio%2520Z715e%26gnt%3D0%26native_templates%3D1%252C2%26ma%3D0%26platform%3DHTC%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D1%26native_version%3D3%26muv%3D15%26riv%3D0%26ms%3DbBaKMM241P7ZUZbIw630exH1iY80ufKc8Z12nKVbEOI4eDpWg2KlW24F0xUKsi7r1FLSD9ISfYeAdN8C_jtjpY6xx5wG5BARDyrZUgeW_qnHTavdTzBzrpSaI1-3y19EgkD3mrsTe5XMetskcd4lTidQnf63xhT8BeE9u1LAJb1pTp_N8TssVCQNtBBRk59fPAK8olxqwKJm-nDWnLngOBSH0F_dXlmb_-ZhxT0VwHw8Hv406I5dXx2jh6YAvc0kd_cJwwBfLhCXEnxqcNCgAhLJWbdnzqf2kYziboXI8BGqqPbVNRNeKqzWB149Ri-q0no25qbKdZIbT0yuMNMkgA%26mv%3D80321300.com.android.vending%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DRU%26request_id%3Dd72e3527-8d9a-4f0c-b771-18f9f922403c%26am%3D0%26native_image_orientation%3Dany%26u_w%3D360%26u_h%3D640%26msid%3Dcom.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26app_name%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26an%3D6.android.com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher%26net%3Dwi%26u_audio%3D3%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D0%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D0%26currts%3D4989768%26pclick%3D0%26basets%3D4989768%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D180%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26gsb%3Dwi%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.55%26cans%3D-1%26canm%3Dfalse%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26tcar%3D46%26jsv%3D176%26urll%3D1435&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1436822617303.
            at null:1
07-14 00:23:37.365    7433-7433/? W/Ads﹕ JS: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
    (null:1)
07-14 00:23:37.365    7433-7433/? W/Web Console﹕ The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
            at null:1
07-14 00:23:38.155    7433-7857/? D/skia﹕ WebFrame::loadStarted (1) about:blank
07-14 00:23:38.276    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.<init>
07-14 00:23:38.286    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.evaluateJavascript
07-14 00:23:38.286    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.isAttachedToWindow, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.onDraw
07-14 00:23:38.286    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6452: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/internal/t/h;.isAttachedToWindow ()Z
07-14 00:23:38.336    7698-7827/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/skia﹕ WebFrame::loadStarted (1) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/native_ads.html
07-14 00:23:38.916    7698-7827/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher D/skia﹕ WebFrame::loadStarted (0) gmsg://mobileads.google.com/nativeAdPreProcess?failure=true&google.afma.Notify_dt=1436822618925
07-14 00:23:38.926    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/Ads﹕ JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/nativeAdPreProcess?failure=true&google.afma.Notify_dt=1436822618925.
    (null:1)
07-14 00:23:38.926    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/Web Console﹕ The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/nativeAdPreProcess?failure=true&google.afma.Notify_dt=1436822618925.
            at null:1
07-14 00:23:38.946    7698-7698/com.clockbyte.vkgroupwatcher W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
```

**Updated 3**
I tried to get the Content ads only (by commenting the corresponding block in the AdLoader.Builder) as @RedBrogdon adviced. Here is the log

```
08-17 12:07:16.806    4918-5025/com.engineers.admobtest54321 D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-973066727.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
08-17 12:07:16.926    4918-5025/com.engineers.admobtest54321 D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads-973066727.jar' (success) ---
08-17 12:07:16.926    4918-5025/com.engineers.admobtest54321 D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.engineers.admobtest54321/cache/ads-973066727.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 123ms
08-17 12:07:16.946    4918-4918/com.engineers.admobtest54321 I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
08-17 12:07:17.566    4918-5055/com.engineers.admobtest54321 I/Ads﹕ Trying mediation network:
08-17 12:07:17.576    4918-4918/com.engineers.admobtest54321 I/Ads﹕ Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter
08-17 12:07:17.576    4918-4918/com.engineers.admobtest54321 W/Ads﹕ Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter. com.google.DummyAdapter
08-17 12:07:17.576    4918-5055/com.engineers.admobtest54321 I/Ads﹕ No fill from any mediation ad networks.
08-17 12:07:17.576    4918-4918/com.engineers.admobtest54321 W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 3
```

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or hardware device? If both, does the behavior change between the two?

Comment: @RedBrogdon Thx for reply. I'm testing on the both and the result is likewise (errorcode 0). But logs are different. I've put it to the **Updated2** section

Comment: Hmm. The missing method warning lines I would expect given the API level of the device, so I don't think that's a problem. Does this occur no matter which format (app install or content) you request? Have you tried commenting them out one at a time to make sure both fail?

Comment: @RedBrogdon Let me check this out and I'll turn back with results...I guess it would be better to try loading of the Native ads in a simple separate project at first...

Comment: @RedBrogdon Hi sorry that I dissapeared for a time, was very busy at another project...But I've tried to get ads in a separate simple project yesterday, also I tried to get app install and content ads separetely, it was also failed. Please take a look at the **UPDATE3** section

Comment: @RedBrogdon Also I tried to change my appname/project namespace , you could see the 54321 numbers in the Logcat :) It hasn't helped, I got the same. I even tried to debug on another PC in the different network :) Failed...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native)

> Note: At the current time, publishers should not use the addTestDevice method with native ad requests. Using the above ad unit ID with calls to addTestDevice is the current best practice for testing.

So try removing calls to `addTestDevice(deviceId)`. I've had same issue and its start working after I've done that.

Comment: Nikolay I tried what you've adviced and I got the error code 0. When I set a test device with addTestDevice(deviceId) and using the provided test ad unit ID I got the error code 3 (I have even created a very simple project to be sure that nothing else get an influence on the ads fetching). Kindly take a look at my **Update 3**. Could you please provide some sample piece of code or a sample project to create an AdLoader in a correct way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finally I got native ad successfully! To be honest I haven't done anything, simply tried to launch my simple test project once again in some time...I'm wondering if the reason was  "I/Ads﹕ No fill from any mediation ad networks.". Man, since your advice helped me to find a correct way I'm glad to mark it as an answer! thx!

Comment: Seems like this is no longer the case and native ads works fine so probably you should update the answer

Answer (score 0):

BTW I decided to post my solution for publishing Native Ads into ListView items to [admobadapter](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter). Hope it will help someone. The **result** will look like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/master/screenshots/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif)

The **basic usage** could look like:

```
    ListView lvMessages;
    AdmobAdapterWrapper adapterWrapper;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initListViewItems();
    }

    /**
     * Inits an adapter with items, wrapping your adapter with a {@link AdmobAdapterWrapper} and setting the listview to this wrapper
     * FIRST OF ALL Please notice that the following code will work on a real devices but emulator!
     */
    private void initListViewItems() {
        lvMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);

        //creating your adapter, it could be a custom adapter as well
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        adapterWrapper = new AdmobAdapterWrapper(this);
        adapterWrapper.setAdapter(adapter); //wrapping your adapter with a AdmobAdapterWrapper.
        //here you can use the following string to set your custom layouts for a different types of native ads
        //adapterWrapper.setInstallAdsLayoutId(R.layout.your_installad_layout);
        //adapterWrapper.setcontentAdsLayoutId(R.layout.your_installad_layout);

        //Sets the max count of ad blocks per dataset, by default it equals to 3 (according to the Admob's policies and rules)
        adapterWrapper.setLimitOfAds(3);

        //Sets the number of your data items between ad blocks, by default it equals to 10.
        //You should set it according to the Admob's policies and rules which says not to
        //display more than one ad block at the visible part of the screen,
        // so you should choose this parameter carefully and according to your item's height and screen resolution of a target devices
        adapterWrapper.setNoOfDataBetweenAds(10);

        //It's a test admob ID. Please replace it with a real one only when you will be ready to deploy your product to the Release!
        //Otherwise your Admob account could be banned
        //String admobUnitId = getResources().getString(R.string.banner_admob_unit_id);
        //adapterWrapper.setAdmobReleaseUnitId(admobUnitId);

        lvMessages.setAdapter(adapterWrapper); // setting an AdmobAdapterWrapper to a ListView

        //preparing the collection of data
        final String sItem = "item #";
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(100);
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            lst.add(sItem.concat(Integer.toString(i)));

        //adding a collection of data to your adapter and rising the data set changed event
        adapter.addAll(lst);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Native Advanced is still in beta, you would have to request to signup with the https://support.google.com/admob/contact/account_setup?rd=1

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a size problem.
Please try with Native Express id:

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312(Small template)

Or refer to: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Answer (score 0):

Might not help everyone, but **DON'T FORGET TO TURN OFF ALL KINDS OF ADBLOCKERS**.

I had a adblocker DNS configured, took me a couple of hours to finally find that out :D